# Mapping table with multiple items

Tags: vba, dictionary, header, mapping, match

I have a mapping table which I use for matching headers of two separate sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet2).
But what if I have something like this (3 columns in the left part, 2 columns in the right):

- Basically I want *POS1 2019 EMP1* to be equal to *HR DEPARTMAENT Employee1* and so on.
  [Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfvoW.png),
  [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXG3d.png),
  [Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfAXO.png)
  Any ideas how can I do it?
  Thank you in advance! :)

  ```
   Public Sub test()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     stack "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Mapping"
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
   Public Sub stack(ByVal Sheet1 As String, ByVal Sheet2 As String, ByVal 
   Mapping As String)
   Dim rng As Range, trgtCell As Range, src As Worksheet, trgt As 
   Worksheet, helper As Worksheet

   Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range
   Dim sht As Worksheet

   Set src = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set trgt = Worksheets("Sheet2")
   Set helper = Worksheets("Mapping")

   With src
       For Each rng In Intersect(.Rows(3), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
           Dim lkup As Variant
           With helper
               lkup = Application.VLookup(rng.Value, .Range("D13:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row), 2, False)
           End With
           If Not IsError(lkup) Then

           Set trgtCell = trgt.Range("$B$2:$F$7").Find(lkup, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

           If Not trgtCell Is Nothing Then
               .Range(rng.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
               With trgt
                   .Range(Split(trgtCell.Address, "$")(1) & 3).PasteSpecial
               End With
           End If
       End If
   Next rng
  ```

  End With
  End Sub

Comment: I cannot understand anything from your question, sorry. I read it twice but still unclear. Can you explain (**in words**) what do you mean by **mapping**? I remember I could see another question from you with a similar situation and I asked why use a `Sub` with parameters, since you do not use none of them. Did you make the above code, or you took it from internet not understanding too much about the way it works?

Comment: @FaneDuru Hi! Sorry for my poorly explanation, I'm new at this.  This is a code from internet but I've adapted it for my situation. Well I have two sheets, each sheet has a different table with headers (but the header is made from 3 or 2 cells-vertically, looks like another little table) and I want to match them, and copy values below header from Sheet2 to Sheet1. Let's say Sheet 1 has a table with a header from B1:F3. And Sheet 2, B1:F2. And I wanna match B1:F3 (Sheet1) with B1:F2(Sheet2) using a mapping table. Still unclear?

Comment: Maybe I am tired, but still not clear (for me...). If you will edit your question and post another picture showing what you want accomplishing, I will maybe understand it...

Comment: Done. I've added some pictures with the tables from those 2 sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think dictionaries are the data structure most suited to this type of problem.
Be aware, to use dictionaries in VBA you need to set a reference to the Scripting Runtime library.

Tools->Reference-> Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Here is some code that works on the example you provided:

```
Public Sub test()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  stack2 "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Mapping"
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


Public Sub stack(ByVal Sheet1 As String, ByVal Sheet2 As String, ByVal Mapping As String)
Dim rng As Range, src As Worksheet, trgt As Worksheet, helper As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim dctCol As Dictionary, dctHeader As Dictionary
Dim strKey1 As String, strKey2 As String
Dim strItem As String, col As Integer

Set src = Worksheets(Sheet1)
Set trgt = Worksheets(Sheet2)
Set helper = Worksheets(Mapping)
        
'build a dictionary to lookup column based on 3 rows of headers
Set dctCol = New Dictionary
arr1 = src.Range("A1:F7") 'arrays are way faster than ranges
For j = 2 To UBound(arr1, 2) 'loop over data from columns B-F
    strKey1 = Trim(arr1(1, j)) & "," & Trim(arr1(2, j)) & "," & Trim(arr1(3, j)) 'comma delimit string
    dctCol(strKey1) = j 'j is the column number
Next

'build a dictionary to translate 2 headers to 3 headers
Set dctHeader = New Dictionary
arrHelp = helper.Range("A2:E6")
For i = 1 To UBound(arrHelp)
    strKey2 = Trim(arrHelp(i, 4)) & "," & Trim(arrHelp(i, 5)) '2 header key
    strItem = Trim(arrHelp(i, 1)) & "," & Trim(arrHelp(i, 2)) & "," & Trim(arrHelp(i, 3))
    dctHeader(strKey2) = strItem
Next

'update sheet2 with numbers from sheet1
arr2 = trgt.Range("A1:F6")
For j = 2 To 5
    'work backwards to find the column
    strKey2 = Trim(arr2(1, 2)) & "," & Trim(arr2(2, j)) '2 headers
    strKey1 = dctHeader(strKey2)
    col = dctCol(strKey1)
    
    'update the data for arr2
    For i = 3 To 6
        arr2(i, j) = arr1(i + 1, col)
    Next
Next

'write it back to spreadsheet
trgt.Range("M10").Resize(UBound(arr2), UBound(arr2, 2)) = arr2
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Thank you for the comments also, they are really helpful. I had a hard time explaining this. Now I just need to figure out how to make this work for the rows header also, since those 2 months are switched. BUT you've been reaaaaaally helpful.  Thank you again sir

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code.

```
Public Sub test()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   stack "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Mapping"
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub stack(ByVal Sheet1 As String, ByVal Sheet2 As String, ByVal Mapping As String)
Dim rng As Range, trgtCell As Range, src As Worksheet, trgt As Worksheet, helper As Worksheet
            
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
            
Set src = Worksheets(Sheet1)
Set trgt = Worksheets(Sheet2)
Set helper = Worksheets(Mapping)
        
With src
    For Each rng In Intersect(.Rows(3), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        Dim lkup As Variant

        With helper
            lkup = Application.VLookup(rng.Value, .Range("C2:E" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row), 3, False)
        End With
        If Not IsError(lkup) Then
                    
            Set trgtCell = trgt.Range("$B$2:$F$7").Find(lkup, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
             Debug.Print trgtCell.Address
            If Not trgtCell Is Nothing Then
                With trgt
                    .Range(trgtCell.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, trgtCell.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy
                End With
                .Range(Split(trgtCell.Address, "$")(1) & 4).PasteSpecial
           End If
        End If
    Next rng
End With
End Sub
```

Please, also correct the sub calling the second one. You mixed "Shee2" with "Sheet1" there...

Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Yea not really what I need. Here is a link for the workbook https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fitQqjw2snOYlxzxXsL29oEmXwLLPVQJ/view?usp=sharing if you have time to take a look, I appreciate. I put the macro there so you can run it.

Comment: My code is working only with a mapping table which has only 2 columns. But I want it to work with the other mapping table (A1:E6) with multiple columns :). I really hope this is more clear now

Comment: @Dodoi What did you send me? Didn't you send the workbook you want to be processed? If I cannot see **what those multiple columns** contain, how to help you doing something I cannot understand what is it about? Now I am leaving my office. I will look at your **real** workbook when I will be at home. Supposing that you will send another one...

Comment: I have edited my post again. I put some pictures with the entire Sheet1, Sheet2 and Mapping Sheet and also you can use that code which is working for the small mapping table. I put my workbook in Drive so you can access it through that link. I gave you permission, so I don't really know why it's not working. Thank you again

Comment: I am driving now. I will post an answer after some hours, when I will be at home.

Comment: @Dodoi I updated the code to use the range "A1:E6" for mapping . Since you did not say anything about this range, until your comment, I cannot be sure that this is what you meant. You were talking about four columns and this range has 5. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: @Dodoi I forgot to send back the working workbook. You can download it from [here](https://easyupload.io/57drqg).